# How to fit text 100% in textangular by default

Tags: angularjs, textangular

when i copy and paste text in textangular editor, it's look like this in the editor.(you can observe in the right side of the pic)

[image]

How to fit the text 100% in textangular editor by default.

HTML:

```
<div class="post-editor" ta-min-text="3" id="iSupportDescription{{$index}}" name="Description" placeholder="Description" text-angular="text-angular" ta-toolbar="[['bold','italics','underline','ul','ol']]" ng-required="true" ng-model="text" ta-safe-sanitizer="true" ta-paste="stripFormat($html)"></div>
```